# `longtabu` does not work well with `sidewaystable`

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu

When `longtabu` is used inside `sidewaystable` environment, the long table cannot spread on multiple pages any more.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{ X[3.1,l] X[6,l] X[6,l] }
      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead

      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endhead

      \midrule
      \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
      \bottomrule
      \endfoot

      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot

      One & abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      \end{longtabu}
    \caption{A table}
  \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, sidewaystable is a one-page environment, use e.g. landscape instead. Regarding longtabu read the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot. I will try using `landscape` instead.

Comment: As a note, `longtabu` does not work well with `landscape` environment as well which makes the `pdflatex` compiler never stop.

Comment: To say it clearly: `tabu` is very buggy nowadays (unmaintained!) Simply do not use it any longer!

Comment: Depending on the actual contents of your table, you might want to use `longtable` or `xltabular` instead of `longtabu`. Probably you don't even need a landscape table.

Answer (score 1):

From the `rotating` documentation:

> The package provides: two new environments, `sidewaystable` and
>   `sidewaysfigure`, each of which produces a **single page-size float** with
>   contents rotated ±90 degrees[...]

Therefore, a multi page table such as `longtabu` can not work inside of a `sidewaystable` environment. To rotate a multi page table, one can use the `landscape` environment from the `pdflatex` package.

Since the `tabu` package (that also provides the `longtabu` package) is no longer mainained, I'd suggest that you switch to `longtable` or (if you hae onger contents in cells and need automatic linebreaks in them to prevent the table from being wider than the textwidth) `xltabular`. Depending on the contents of your actual table, there is probably not even the need to rotate the table at all. (
(Your example table needs more than a page in landscape but can fit into a single page in portrait orientation.)

Lastly, I'd also suggest that you move the caption of the table so that it is displayed above instead of below the table:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXl}
   \caption{A table}\\
      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead

      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endhead

      \midrule
      \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
      \bottomrule
      \endfoot

      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot

      One & abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      \end{xltabular}
  \end{landscape}


      \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXl}
   \caption{A table}\\
      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead

      \toprule
      Paper & Passing order & Longitudinal control \\ 
      \midrule
      \endhead

      \midrule
      \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
      \bottomrule
      \endfoot

      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot

      One & abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn abcdef ghjijklmn & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
      \end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```